# .eslintignore exclusions not applying when launching eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintignore

Here is my project architecture :

[image: Code Architecture]

My .eslintignore :

```
/public/*
/test/*
```

These two folders are located at **client/public** && **client/test** but for some reason when starting eslint, it still lints my excluded files.

I am launching eslint through this command :

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint . -c ../.eslintrc.js
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/client/public/*
/client/test/*
```